# Laravel 9 and ReactJS App gets a 401 unauthorized with api.php router and build-in Passport Authentication in Laravel for Cross-domain Authentication

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

I am made an App with Laravel 9 back-end and ReactJS front-end and get a 401 unauthorized error even I am successfully logged-in in to my App. For Authentication I am using Laravel's build-in Passport and Cross-Domain Middleware.

Code is in api.php router and looks like below:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'users', 'middleware' => 'CORS'], function ($router) {

    Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register'])->name('register.auth');

    Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login.auth');

    Route::get('/userdata', [AuthController::class, 'userData'])->name('userdata.auth');

    Route::get('/checkifemailverified/{token}', [AuthController::class, 'checkIfEmailVerified'])->name('user.verify');

    Route::get('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout.auth');

    Route::get('/me', [AuthController::class, 'me'])->name('me.auth');

});
```

And here is a AuthController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Auth;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\UserVerify;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AuthController extends Controller
{

//private $apiToken;
protected $user;

public function __construct()
{
    //$this->apiToken = uniqid(base64_encode(Str::random(40)));
    $this->middleware("auth:api",["except" => ["login","register","logout","verifyAccount","checkIfEmailVerified","me"]]);
    $this->user = new User;
}

/** 
* 
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response 
*/ 
  
public function login(Request $request){
    
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'email' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|min:8',
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){
        return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'message' => $validator->messages()->toArray()
        ], 500);
    }
    //User check
    
    $credentials = $request->only(["email","password"]);
    $user = User::where('email',$credentials['email'])->first();
    if($user->is_active===1){
    
        if(auth()->attempt($credentials)){
            
            //$user = Auth::user();
            
            if($user->email_verified_at !== NULL){
            
                if (DB::table('domains')
                    ->select('domain', 'valid_before')
                    ->where('domain', $user->domain)
                    ->whereDate('valid_before_at', '<=', Carbon::now())
                    ->count()){
                        return response()->json([
                           'success' => false,
                           'data' => 'Username and password do not match or domain subscription is not valid or expired!'
                        ], 200);
                    
                } else { 
                     // Login and "remember" the given user...
                    //Auth::login($user, true); 
                    //Setting login response 
                    $accessToken = auth()->user()->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;
                    /*$success['token'] = $this->apiToken;
                    $success['name'] =  $user->name;
                    return response()->json([
                       'success' => true,
                       'data' => $success
                    ], 200);*/
                    $responseMessage = "Login Successful";
                    return $this->respondWithToken($accessToken,$responseMessage,auth()->user());
                }

            } else {
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => false,
                    'data' => 'Please Verify Email!'
                ], 200);
            }
            
        } else {
            //$success['success'] = false;
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'data' => 'Username and password do not match or domain subscription is not valid or expired!'
            ], 200);
              
        }
    }
}

public function register(Request $request){
    
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'email' => 'required|string',
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'domain' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|min:8',
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){
        return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'message' => $validator->messages()->toArray()
        ], 500);
    }
    
    DB::beginTransaction();

    try {
        
        DB::table('domains')->insert([
            ['domain' => $request->domain, 'valid_before_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+30 day")), 'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]
        ]);
    
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            ['name' => $request->name, 'email' => $request->email, 'password' => Hash::make($request->password), 'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'domain' => $request->domain]
        ]);
        
        DB::commit();
        
        // all good
        /*return response()->json([
                    'success' => true,
                    'data' => 'User and domain is now created!'
                  ], 200);*/
                  
        try {

            $id = DB::table('users')
                        ->select('id')
                        ->where('email', $request->email)
                        ->first()->id;
                
            $token = Str::random(64);
            
            DB::table('users_verify')->insert([
                ['user_id' => $id, 'token' => $token, 'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]
            ]);
            
            Mail::send('emails.userverify', ['token' => $token], function($message) use($request){
                $message->from(env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'), env('MAIL_FROM_NAME'));
                $message->to($request->email);
                $message->subject('Email Verification Mail');
            });
            
            return response()->json([
                    'success' => true,
                    'data' => 'User and domain is now created!'
                  ], 200);
        
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // something went wrong
            return response()->json([
                        'success' => false,
                        'data' => $e->getMessage()
                      ], 200);
        }
        
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        // something went wrong
        return response()->json([
                    'success' => false,
                    'data' => $e->getMessage()
                  ], 200);
    }       
}

/**
* Write code on Method
*
* @return response()
*/
public function verifyAccount($token)
{
    $verifyUser = UserVerify::where('token', $token)->first();
    $message = 'Sorry your email cannot be identified.';
    if(!is_null($verifyUser) ){
        $user = $verifyUser->user;
        if($user->email_verified_at == null) {
            $verifyUser->user->email_verified_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $verifyUser->user->save();
            $message = "Your e-mail is verified. You can now login.";
        } else {
            $message = "Your e-mail is already verified. You can now login.";
        }
    }
    return redirect(env('APP_UI_URL').'/verifyemail?token='.$token);
}


/**
* Write code on Method
*
* @return response()
*/
public function checkIfEmailVerified($token)
{
    $verifyUser = UserVerify::where('token', $token)->first();
    $message = 'Sorry your email cannot be identified.';
    if(!is_null($verifyUser) ){
        $user = $verifyUser->user;
        if($user->email_verified_at == null) {
            $message = "Your e-mail is verified. You can now login.";
        } else {
            $message = "Your e-mail is already verified. You can now login.";
        }
    }
    return response()->json([
                    'success' => true,
                    'data' => $message
                  ], 200);
}

/**
* Logout the current user and revokes its crenedials.
*
* @return response()
*/
public function logout(Request $request){
    $user = Auth::guard("api")->user()->token();
    $user->revoke();
    $responseMessage = "successfully logged out";
    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => $responseMessage
    ], 200);
}

/**
 * Get the user's profile.
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function userData(Request $request)
{
    $data = Auth::guard("api")->user();
    //var_dump($user);
    
    return $data;
}


/**
 * Get the user's profile name.
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function me(Request $request)
{
    $data = Auth::guard("api")->user();
    //var_dump($data);
    
    return $data;
}
}
```

Purpose is to get logged-in users details for ReactJS GUI with userdata route and/or me router user name E.g Matti Kiviharju.

Also if anyone wants to see whole source codes of am App there re publically here in my GIT repositories in Atlassian Bitbucket for investigation:

React Front-end: https://bitbucket.i4ware.fi/projects/LOG/repos/login-form/browse?at=refs%2Fheads%2Fmatti_0006

Laravel Back-end: https://bitbucket.i4ware.fi/projects/SAAS/repos/saas-app/browse?at=refs%2Fheads%2Fmatti_0008

**However, right answer for this that solves a problem helps multiple people, because source codes is available on our public GIT repos.**

Comment: Your default guard is `web`  in the config/auth.php you shared in your sources. For API routes you need to use `auth:api` to use the api guard (or just switch the default guard to api). Also it's not clear how and where you actually use in your front-end, the token you are generating for a logged in user

Comment: This not help even I add auth:api to Kernel.php.

Comment: The Front-end Token is stored in ReactJS for check is user logged-in or not and it come to destroyed when I press a logout button.

Comment: In LoginForm.js axios request has this code: localStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME,json_parsed.data.data.token);

Comment: And in Home.js has a this axios request: axios.get(API_BASE_URL+'/api/me', { headers: { 'token': localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME) }})

Comment: Also I found these tutorials with using Google: https://medium.com/technology-hits/laravel-react-fullstack-application-with-passport-redux-and-material-ui-backend-1c4b38b08b01 and https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport ; But these not help.

Comment: That I am noticed the authentication does not work because my React App is in localkost:3000 and Laravel App in localhost so authentication does not work on crossdomain without JWT and Laravel's build in Passport accessToken system.